# Stream MP4 using FFMPEG on remote VLC

Tags: linux, video, ffmpeg, embedded-linux, android-7.0-nougat

I'm trying to stream a MP4 file from my Embedded device and play it in the VLC in my laptop. My H/W setup look like below

```
--------------                ------------------      
|  Board     |     Ethernet   | Window Laptop  |
| (Android N)|----------------|     VLC        | 
| 192.168.1.5|                |  192.168.1.2   |  
|   ffmpeg   |                |----------------|
|------------|
```

I'm trying to issue ffmpeg command from board side and it look like below

Embedded board --- 
    ./ffmpeg -re -i vid.mp4  -vcodec copy -an -f rtp rtp://192.168.1.2:1234 -vn -acodec copy -f rtp rtp://192.168.1.2:1234

On Laptop VLC side my sdp file look like below

```
v=0
o=- 453271780569021 453271780586833 IN IP4 /192.168.1.5
s=Unnamed
i=N/A
c=IN IP4 /192.168.1.2
t=0 0
a=recvonly
m=video 1234 RTP/AVP 96
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
```

I don't see any stream on VLC side. I believe there is something wrong command which I couldn't figured yet. Please let me know if anyone knows how I can achieve this. By the way the video file is not limited to MP4 format , i'm open for any file format.

Thanks, Satish

Comment: `-an` and `-vn` means _audioNone_ and _videoNone_ respectively, so don't use them if you really want some a/v data to get sent... Also what happens if you replace `rtp://192...` etc with `udp://192...`? See if FFmpeg's [**streaming guide**](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/StreamingGuide) helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for Suggestion. Actually I was able to get it working. I just modified my SDP file like below (it was simply the copy/paste the SDP content generated from ffmpeg command).

```
v=0
o=- 0 0 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=No Name
t=0 0
a=tool:libavformat 57.57.100
m=video 1234 RTP/AVP 96
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.2
b=AS:612
a=rtpmap:96 H264/90000
a=fmtp:96 packetization-mode=1; sprop-parameter-sets=J0LgHqkYFAX/LgDUGAQa2wrXvfAQ,KN4JyA==; profile-level-id=42E01E
m=audio 1234 RTP/AVP 97
c=IN IP4 192.168.1.2
b=AS:65
a=rtpmap:97 MPEG4-GENERIC/22050/2
a=fmtp:97 profile-level-id=1;mode=AAC-hbr;sizelength=13;indexlength=3;indexdeltalength=3; config=1390
```

Thanks, Satish